# How to hide spring boot banner.txt in junit test with SpringJUnit4TestRunner?

Tags: java, junit, spring-boot

When I configure an Spring Boot Application, I can disable the banner via run configuration in the static main method. So far so good.

But what if I have the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes={MyApplication.class})
public class MyApplicationTest { 
  ....
}
```

When I run this test, it does not use the static main method and the banner is displayed, making it harder to focus on the relevant logging statements.

Is there a switch or config annotation I can use to simulate `new SpringApplication(MayApplicationclass).setShowBanner(false)...`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put this in your test properties:

```
spring.main.show_banner=false
```

Comment: I think the syntax is now: `spring.main.banner-mode=off`

Comment: I'm unclear what file this would be (as in: I tried a few things I could come up with, to no avail). A hint would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You can specify the property in your test annotation:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties="spring.main.banner-mode=off")
```

Answer (score 6):

Placing an empty banner.txt file in src/test/resources will stop the banner from being displayed while running tests.

Comment: Also, if you put a single line in `banner.txt`, and use the `set nofixeol` feature in vim to strip the trailing EOL, you can get a delimiting line in your output that is easily grep'd for.